# GCM Connection Server - URL difference

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have a app server that uses https: //android.googleapis.com/gcm/send until now works correctly. The documentation indicated to use https: //gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send. Should I change it? or is it the same?

thk, regards

Answer (score 0):

Being update with google documentations is a strong recommendation, but as google did not deprecate the first [url](http://https:%20//android.googleapis.com/gcm/send), you may use it.